# How to center a scrollable text in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a big text in the middle that can be multiple line. I wrapped it under a scroll view because the text could be very long. When the text does not fit the whole screen, I want to center place the text. I have the following code:

```
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("2 / 5")
      Spacer()
      ScrollView([.vertical]) {
        Text("This is a joke. Multiple line is supported. This is a joke. Multiple line is supported. This is a joke. Multiple line is supported. ")
          .fontWeight(.bold)
          .font(.system(.title, design: .rounded))
          .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
      }
      Spacer()
      HStack {
        Button("Prev") {
          // go to prev page
        }
        Spacer()
        Button("Next") {
          // go to next page
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

However, the text is always on the top. Setting a fixed height works, but I don't want to hardcode any value here. I have also tried putting ScrollView under another VStack, with a spacing, but it has no effects.

[image]

Comment: Do you want the text to be in the center of the scrollview or do you want the scrollview to be in the center of the screen?

Comment: @JohnSorensen I just want the appearance of centered text when it does not take up the full screen. So I am fine with either way you come up with

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need `minHeight` for `Text` as screen (dynamic height), so when it is smaller than screen then it will be centered (by default alignment) if it is large - then just grows as needed.

Here is fixed body (tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2):

[image: demo]

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        VStack {
            Text("2 / 5")

            Spacer()

            ScrollView {
                Text("This is a joke. Multiple line is supported. This is a joke. Multiple line is supported. This is a joke. Multiple line is supported. ")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.system(.title, design: .rounded))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .frame(minHeight: proxy.size.height)  // << here !!
            }

            Spacer()

            HStack {
                Button("Prev") {}
                Spacer()
                Button("Next") {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow can you explain more about this `frame(minHeight: proxy.size.height)` and why it works?

Comment: Elegant solution, `ScrollView` default height behavior is fill spacing, it's better to remove two `Spacer()` and move `GeometryReader` to cover `ScrollView` only

Comment: @QuangHà can you explain why remove spacer?